# Third condition in definition of summability kernel?

Tags: fejer-kernel

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summability_kernel

The third condition of the definition involving $\delta$, I don't understand what it is trying to say.
Why would the integral go to 0, when condition 1 says otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it is saying is that the mass concentrates around 0. For large enough $n$, basically all the function is in the region $|t|<\delta$, i.e.

$$1 = \int_{\mathbb T} k_n(t) \ dt \approx \int_{|t|<\delta} k_n(t) \ dt$$

Check the example of the [Fejer kernels.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) The picture from that page: [image] As $n$ increases, the function becomes taller, but also most of the integral comes from a small region around 0, in a way that the total area is fixed (condition 1)

Comment: ohhh, so the integral bound is saying as $n \rightarrow 0$, for the region $\delta < |x| < a$, there is not a lot of "mass" in that region (as it is now centered around x = 0). Makes sense now, thanks!

Comment: @MinYoungKim you're welcome